# I have to drop two times a image to add a class what modification required

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 5 pieces of a image in a container which i have to drop in another container to complete the image. After the image is dropped in another container i want to add a different class to that image depending upon its ID. so that this image piece will stick to the previous image present in this container.

I am able to implement the drag and drop event and add a different class to each image depending upon its ID after drop event. But i have to drop two times a image piece in 2nd container to add a class. what changes i need to make in my code so that class will be added on 1st drop only.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
     connectWith: "div"
     });

    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
     connectWith: "div",
     stop: function( event, ui ) {
         var theID = ui.item.attr('id');
         ui.item.addClass(theID + '-style');
         }
    });


    });
```

**CSS**

```
.north-img-style { position:absolute;top: 280px;left: 850px;}  
.south-img-style { position:absolute;top: 515px;left: 848px;}
.east-img-style {  position:absolute;top: 280px;left: 1190px;}
.west-img-style {  position:absolute;top: 278px;left: 853px;}
.center-img-style {position:absolute;top: 378px;left: 1050px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row-fluid" >
<div class="span4">
    <div class="span1"></div>
    <div id="sortable1" class="well span10">

        <h6 class='bg-title'><img src="/static/images/icons/Pocket.png" alt="collect"  style="height:50px"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Collect Coupon parts</h6>
        <hr>
        <span class="form-group label span3" >1st &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="input-icon fui-image"></i></span>
        <img id="north-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/north.png' %}" >
        <span class="form-group label span3" >2nd &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="input-icon fui-image"></i></span>
        <img id="south-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/south.png' %}" >
        <span class="form-group label span3" >3rd &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="input-icon fui-image"></i></span>
        <img id="east-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/east.png' %}" >
        <span class="form-group label span3" >4th &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="input-icon fui-image"></i></span>
        <img id="west-img"   src="{% static 'images/demo/west.png' %}" >
        <span class="form-group label span3" >5th &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="input-icon fui-image"></i></span>
        <img id="center-img"  src="{% static 'images/demo/center.png' %}" >
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="sortable2"  class="well span7" style="height:800px">
    <span class='bg-title'><img src="/static/images/icons/save.png" alt="save" style="height:50px"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Save your coupons</span>
    <hr>

    </div>
    <div class="span1"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace stop with change event

```
$(function() {

    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
     connectWith: "div"
     });

    $( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
     connectWith: "div",
     change: function( event, ui ) {
           var theID = ui.item.attr('id');
           ui.item.addClass(theID + '-style');
        }
    });


 });
```

For more information please take a look at http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Best

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked. But can you please explain why it worked with change.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This...**

```
$( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
 connectWith: ".well span10" //class id
 });

$( "#sortable2" ).sortable({
 connectWith: ".well span7", // class id
 stop: function( event, ui ) {
     var theID = ui.item.attr('id');
     ui.item.addClass(theID + '-style');
     }
});
```